# How to adjust multiple equations in a single line in latex?

Tags: equations

With reference to following figure, I want to adjust the last line (which has two terms) after the block of three equations inside `aligned` structure, so that all equations appear in a single line while last two terms are parallel to first two or last two lines inside `aligned` structure.

[image]

I am using following latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[total={6.8 in,9.1 in},top=1.1 in, left=0.8 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate,amsmath,graphicx,setspace,bm,mathdesign,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
\bm{\Sigma}^{*}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{PE})&=&\bm{B}^{-1}-2\left[
\begin{aligned}
\bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{-1}\Psi_{p_{2}+2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)\nonumber\\
+\bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2}+4}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)\nonumber\\
-\bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2}+2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)
\end{aligned}\right]\\
&&+\bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{-1}\Psi_{p_{2}+2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)+\bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2}+4}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)\nonumber\\
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

My desired output would look like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by parallel? "first two or last two", do you need two different approaches?

Comment: My aligned structure has 3 terms in 3 rows and I want to adjust my last two terms adjacent to these 3 terms (which means either I will write my last two terms against first two terms of the aligned structure or against the last two terms of the aligned structure) which ever is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if I got you right, but here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[%
    ,total={6.8 in,9.1 in}
    ,top=1.1 in
    ,left=0.8 in
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \bm{\Sigma}^{*}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{PE})=\bm{B}^{-1}-2
        \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
            \bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{-1}\Psi_{p_{2}+2}(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta)\\[\jot]
            {}+\bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2}+4}(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta)\\[\jot]
            {}-\bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2}+2}(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta)
        \end{bmatrix*}\begin{matrix*}[l]
            {}+\bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{-1}\Psi_{p_{2}+2}(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta)\\[\jot]
            {}+\bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2}+4}(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta)\\[\jot]
            {}
        \end{matrix*}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Some remarks:

- don't use `eqnarray`, it is outdated.
- try not to use the automatic parentheses to often, as they result in bad spacing sometimes.
- introduce custom commands in order to make the code easier to read and to keep it flexible for future modifications. E.g. `\newcommand*{\myVec}[1]{\hat{\bm{#1}}}`

Comment: @KashifAli Glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Comment: I didn't pick your last remark. Would you explain it to me?

Comment: @KashifAli Sure. Right now, I read `\hat{\bm{\beta}` and have no idea what it means. If it was something like `\myVec{\beta}`, a code reviewer (which could be you in some time) can understand it much better. Good practise for programming. And, if suddenly your lector says "we do not want to load `bm`" or "myVecs have to be sains serif for some reason", you can change this in your `newcommand` in the preamble and you are done. Just imagine the work you get, if the journal's font does forbid bold characters. (Just use cases... you get the point, I hope)

Comment: Got your point @LaRiFaRi. Will try to implement and by the way, thanks for helping me so quickly.

Comment: Very nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

I propose two solutions: with a `multline` environment, and with `aligned` together with the facilities of `mathtools`, which extends (and loads) `amsmath`. I don't this the split equation that looks like a matrix is a good layout – unless I didn't understand what you meant.

Note `eqnarray` shouldn't be used: use `align` from `amsmath` instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[total={6.8 in,9.1 in},top=1.1 in, left=0.8 in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \bm{\Sigma}^{*}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{PE}) = \bm{B}^{ - 1} - 2\Bigl[\bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{ - 1}\Psi_{p_{2} + 2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)
  + \bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2} + 4}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right) \\ - \bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2} + 2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right) \Bigr] + \bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{ - 1}\Psi_{p_{2} + 2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right) + \bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2} + 4}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)
\end{multline}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \MoveEqLeft[-1.5]\mathllap{\bm{\Sigma}^{*}(\hat{\bm{\beta}}^{PE}) =}\\
    \bm{B}^{ - 1} & - 2\Bigl[\bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{ - 1}\Psi_{p_{2} + 2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)+ \bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2} + 4}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right) - \bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}' \bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2} + 2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)\Bigr] \\
                  & + \bm{J}\bm{R}\bm{B}^{ - 1}\Psi_{p_{2} + 2}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right) + \bm{J}\bm{\delta}\bm{\delta}'\bm{J}'\Psi_{p_{2} + 4}\left(\chi^{2}_{p_{2},\alpha};\Delta\right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This first solution is useful too. Thanks @Bernard.